# What is the probability of my sum reaching exactly 10?

Tags: probability, dice

I throw a 6-sided dice (with values: 0,1,2,3,4,5) multiple times and add each value to a sum, which is 0 in the beginning. What is the probability of my sum reaching exactly 10, 11, 12, 13, 14? After reaching a requested sum, the sum will return to it's original 0 value.

E.g: 5 + 5 = 10, and afterwards the sum returns to 0. 
Also, the probability for each number on the dice is different (it's not a fair dice).

Comment: How many times, did you say???

Comment: I assume you mean rolling a die twice. If this is the case, you would divide the number of ways to roll a $10$ by the total number of outcomes when rolling a die twice.

Comment: I think it means: keep rolling the die and keep track of the sum, then ask: What is the probability that the sum of 10 is obtained in such a sequence of rolls. We don't know in advance how many rolls, in fact one could roll a lot of zeroes and have to keep going for example. But with probability 1 a given sequence eventually gets to 10 or more, after which one knows whether it counts toward the desired event or not. Is this the intent, Reka M?

Comment: For **exactly** $2$ throws, the probability is $\frac{1}{36}$. For **exactly** $3$ throws, the probability is $\frac{19}{216}$. Due to the $0$ value on your die (the singular version of "dice"), it gets more and more complicated with each additional throw. This is a question for experts (+1 for that)!

Comment: Maybe this can help: the probability is the same assuming that the dice has only 5 faces with numbers $1,2,3,4,5$, just ignoring the zeroes (the probability of the event "a number larger than 10 is never reached" is $0$). In this case you can proceed with a monotonic finite Markov Chain.

Comment: @Crostul: I think that with the value $0$ at hand, the probability is larger than $0$, as it seems that for every number of $2$ throws or more you have a fair amount of combinations that sum up to $10$. In particular, just by adding a $0$ to each of the combinations of the previous experiment (with one throw less), you get a large amount of combinations that sum up to $10$ in the current experiment.

Comment: @coffeemath : you understood my problem exactly. We do not know in advance how many rolls we will have to reach the sum 10.

Comment: But you can just ignore the zero throws, and pretend that the non-zero throws each have probability $\frac15$. And then the number of non-zero throws required is at most 10.

Comment: [The three revisions of your post](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/910821/revisions) are all *completely different* questions. Which one do you want answered?

Comment: @AakashM : the last one, as it is the complete version of my problem.

Comment: The current version is still unclear. When you 'return to its original value', do you *keep going*? If so, you'll *almost surely* reach all the 'requested sums', so long as there is some combination of rolls to get there from zero with non-zero probability.

Comment: I have the same question as AakashM, when you get to zero you keep going?

Answer (score 6):

It pays to generalize. Let's calculate the probability $p(n)$ that 
we ever reach $n$ for *any integer * $n$.

Since we start at zero, we have $p(0)=1$, while  $p(n)=0$ 
for $n<0$.

For larger $n$, by conditioning on the previously taken value 
we get $$p(n)=\sum_{j=0}^5 p(n-j)/6,$$
and if you solve this recursive equation for $n=10$ you 
get $$p(10)={3327696\over 9765625}=.34076.$$

For large values of $n$ the probability $p(n)$ will 
be very close to $1/3$, since each die throw adds three
 (on average) to the total.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland: Thank you for your answer. I will try this approach as well.

Answer (score 3):

(Note: This is the solution to the problem in its original form.)

Denote by $q(n)$ the probability that we hit $10$, given that the momentary sum is $n$ and we have not hit $10$ before. Then
$$q(10)=1;\qquad q(n)=0\quad(11\leq n\leq14)\ .$$
Furthermore we have the following backwards recursion:
$$q(n)=\sum_{k=1}^5 {1\over5} q(n+k)\qquad(n=9,8,7,\ldots)\ .$$
This formula reflects the fact that  the next move forward is one of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with equal probability.

Performing the recursion gives
$$q(0)={3327696\over9765625}\ ,$$
as determined by Byron Schmuland with another argument.

Comment: I have replaced in the formula the specific probabilities for each value, but unfortunately, the results are not convincing. I've created a simulation of this problem, so I know approximately what my results should be. I just need the calculation nethod, and this doesn't seem to be it :( .

Comment: What are the probabilities for each number then?

Comment: @bobbym: the probabilities are: 0 - 92.77495997% ;
1 - 7.00000000% ;
2 - 0.22000000% ;
3 - 0.00500000% ;
4 - 0.00004000% ;
5 - 0.00000003%

Comment: Hi Reka; I am getting 96.91%